# With RealVNC and a Raspberry Pi, how can I connect to the same session as the raspberry itself?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, vnc, vnc-server

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Wheezy installed. I'm using TightVNC server on the Raspberry Pi and RealVNC on my MAC to connect to it. However, when I log in with RealVNC, I'm given a new session, with my own desktop, applications etc.

I want to login to the SAME session as the already running Raspberry, so I can refresh the browser etc (We're using this to display a company desktop application).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is supported by TightVNC (which I think only does "Virtual" sessions). But I may be wrong...

The answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/27044/how-to-vnc-into-an-existing-x-session suggests a few alternatives (at least ones which work on Fedora based Unix distros)

I know RealVNC can do it (it's known as "User Mode" or "Service Mode" as opposed to "Virtual Desktop" mode), but depending on your users, you may have to license it, or the free mode may suffice.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this with RealVNC, everything else is a suggestion to use a different vnc version. I have RealVNC running as it's default installed for the pi.  So I don't even know where the config stuff is located.